# Achieving safe dereference in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dereference

I am investigating using the jQuery object as a safe de-referencer like they have in Groovy.  The issue I am trying to solve is I retrieve JSON from AJAX calls that may not have the values I am looking for.  I would like a convenience method to check whether I get a value back before attempting to do something with that value.

For non-Groovy programmers, if a variable in Groovy is null, the methods calling it fail silently rather than throw null pointer exceptions.

I can create an empty object out of a null variable by using the jQuery operator like so:

```
var myvar
$(myvar).chainedfunc()
```

In this example, chainedfunc will still execute on the empty object.

Is there a way to prevent chainedfunc from executing if the original value was null?

I understand that I may have to live with performing the chained functions on an empty object.

Note:

### I'm leaving the thought below for the record, but I realize the logic is wrong.  Case 1, the object is null in which case there is no type so no way to create a new object of the same type, case 2 the object exists in which case I return the object unchanged.  The overall question still makes sense though.

In that case, the concern becomes what if the original value was not an object, but an array, since I created an object out of it in order to avoid the null error.  For that situation I have the following function:

```
$.fn.safe = function(){
    if (this.get(0)){
        return this.get(0)
    }
    else return []
}
```

In this case I am assuming the original was an array.  Ideally I would like to be able to determine the type of the original and return an empty instance of the same type.

```
// this does not work because type is not a constructor
$.fn.safe = function(){
    var type = typeof this.get(0)
    return this.get(0) || new type()
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a [law of the instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) issue.

Comment: Clever.  This is why I ask, there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery for this?  You can either just create your own set of functions that operate on your data that all check the integrity of the data before doing anything with it or you can create your own object with methods where the methods check the data.  That's all that jQuery is doing.

Regular functions:

```
function func1(data, arg) {
    if (!data) return;
    // carry out func1 on data here
}

function func2(data, arg) {
    if (!data) return;
    // carry out func2 on data here
}
```

Or as an object:

```
function dWrap(data) {
    this.data = data;
}

dWrap.protototype = {
    func1: function(arg) {
        if (!this.data) return(this);
        // do func1 operation here
        return(this);
    }

    func2: function(arg) {
        if (!this.data) return(this);
        // do func2 operation here
        return(this);
    }
    toString: function() {
        if (!this.data) {
            return("");
        }
        return(this.data.toString());
    }
};

var myData = 45;
var x = new dWrap(myData);
x.func1(3).func2("foo");
x.toString();                     // returns "45"

var y = new dWrap(null);
y.func1(3).func2("foo").toString();   // returns ""
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It's not so much why am I using jQuery, it's that I'm already using jQuery and looking at what I can get for free.  I can turn a null into an empty jQuery object for free, I'm just looking at whether there's a way to optimize it.  I understand it's a simple thing I'm trying to do, what I'm looking for is the best way to do it.

Comment: @saranicole - If your data isn't DOM objects, then you're likely not going to be using other jQuery methods.  If you're not using other jQuery methods, then the only jQuery thing you get for free is the constructor which is a couple lines of code in the above example for your own object.  I personally think it's much cleaner to have your own implementation rather than overload a jQuery implementation with methods that operate on different types of data.

Comment: Fair point.  So taking your regular functions then, the problem still remains if I have a function trying to use a null variable: func1(myvar).toString()  throws an error of "variable undefined."

Comment: @saranicole - if you want `toString()` to be a safe function, then you have to define that method with your own "safe" implementation or make sure that `func1` always returns something that `toString()` can operate on.  I feel a bit like I'm chasing my tail here as you haven't really described your full requirements.

Comment: I appreciate your thought on the question.  My ideal expected behavior is that the function called on a null value would not execute, as if I were to code it: if (myvar){dosomething()}.  If the value is null, dosomething never executes.  It doesn't seem that far-fetched to me to have this functionality, since it's very helpful in Groovy.

Comment: @saranicole - I added `toString()` to my dWrap object example in my answer.  You can wrap/protect any method you want using the object approach.